# android webview is not updating properly

Tags: android, html, html5-canvas

I am developing a game using html5 canvas and I am using android webview to display it. I am getting the touch events using "OnTouchListener" and I am passing it to javascript methods. For this purpose, I am using view.loadUrl("javascript:functionName()") to call javascript method.

Now, For every onTouch event, I am calling a drawline method(in js) with touch event x and y coordinates. But, only first few lines are drawn always and after that, even if I move my finger over the screen, nothing is drawn until the touch event is finished. When the touch event completes, all lines are displayed at once.

From the result, I can conclude that my js method is called with proper x,y value(as all lines are drawn properly), but webview is not updating (as lines are not drawn while moving the finger).

Is there any api which will force webview to update the view in some interval. Thanks in advance.

```
class myTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ZentriangleActivity.zWebView.loadUrl("javascript:drawline("+(int)event.getX()+","+(int)event.getY()+")");
        return false;
    }   
}

myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());
```

***in js code***

```
function drawline(x,y){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(25,25);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: please add code example of what you have right now? Are you already using the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE for sending the x,y coordinates?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added my test code. From the code, you can see, there should be a line drawn for each touch event fired. But as I have told earlier, drawline method is getting called properly, but the view is not updated. When I start moving my finger on screen, only first few lines are drawn, then nothing happens until the touch event ends ... When I remove my finger from screen, suddenly all lines are shown.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this yet? I have similar problems

Comment: No .. i guess this is a threading issue. Don't know how loadUrl method is implemented. Looks like, it is blocking the "onTouch" method and it is not returning. Now, I will call the loadurl in a separate thread and will see what happens. May be we need to dig a little bit into android code.